# How to determine if this series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, trigonometric-series, absolute-convergence

Does this series converge?
I tried using limit comparison, and I don't know what to try next...

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(1-\cos (\pi/n)) $$

Comment: $\displaystyle\large 1 - \cos\left(\,\pi \over n\,\right) \sim {\pi^{2} \over 2}\,{1 \over n^{2}}\quad\mbox{when}\quad n\ \ggg\ 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove by various methods that if $x$ is small then
$$1-\cos x<\frac{x^2}{2}\ .$$
So if $n$ is large then
$$1-\cos\Bigl(\frac\pi n\Bigr)<\Bigl(\frac{\pi^2}2\Bigr)\frac1{n^2}\ ,$$
and you can use a comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **the Maclaurin expansion** for $\cos x$:
$$
\cos (x) = 1 -\frac{x^2}{2}+ \mathcal{O}(x^4)
$$
giving
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left( 1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^4})
$$
concluding that your initial series **converges**.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1-\cos\left(\pi/n\right)\leq\int_0^\infty 1-\cos\left(\pi/x\right)dx=\pi^{2}/2
$$

Comment: how does the last equality come?